Efficiently Extracting Closest Non-NA Raster Value For Each Point Location
I have a raster stack of environmental variables, and a bunch of site points. I want to know the cell value of each raster for a given point location. This is normally handled quickly using terra, however the specific dataset i'm working with has many points that fall slightly outside the boundary of a few rasters and therefore returning NA values.
I've seen similar questions asked on here, and loosely modelled my script after the solutions. The code executes correctly, however I'm having issues scaling this solution to my large rasterstack and points dataset. It's simply too slow and mainly for two reasons:

The get_nearest_non_na function uses terra::distance to compute the distance from each each cell to each point, and this can take a long time to generate when iterated over.

The for loop iterates this process for each raster


Creating Reproducible Dataset
# Load required libraries
library(terra)
library(sf)

# Create raster stack
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f)
r <- rep(r, 3) * 1:3
names(r) <- paste0("var", 1:3)

# Generate spatial points dataset
extent <- as.polygons(ext(r)) |> st_as_sf()
set.seed(99)
pnts <- st_sample(extent, size = 20, type = "random") |> st_as_sf() |> sf::st_set_crs(crs(r))

Function to Handle NA Values
# This function finds the nearest non-NA raster value for a given point
get_nearest_non_na <- function(point, raster_layer) {
  # Compute distance to all raster cells
  distance_raster <- terra::distance(raster_layer, point)
  
  # Extract distances and raster values
  distances <- terra::values(distance_raster)
  raster_values <- terra::values(raster_layer)
  
  # Identify non-NA raster cells
  valid_indices <- which(!is.na(raster_values))
  
  # Find the nearest valid cell by minimizing distance
  nearest_valid_index <- valid_indices[which.min(distances[valid_indices])]
  
  # Return the value of the nearest valid raster cell
  return(raster_values[nearest_valid_index])
}

Using Above function within a for loop
# Iterate over each raster in the stack and apply the function
for (i in 1:nlyr(r)) {
  raster_layer <- r[[i]]
  
  # Extract raster values at point locations
  extracted_values <- terra::extract(raster_layer, pnts, method = "simple")
  
  # Replace NA values with the nearest non-NA raster values
  corrected_values <- sapply(1:nrow(pnts), function(j) {
    if (is.na(extracted_values[j, 2])) {  # If the extracted value is NA
      get_nearest_non_na(pnts[j, ], raster_layer)  # Use the nearest valid value
    } else {
      extracted_values[j, 2]  # Keep the extracted value if it is not NA
    }
  })
  
  # Add the corrected values as a new column to the spatial dataset
  pnts[[names(raster_layer)]] <- corrected_values
}

# View the updated dataset with the new raster values
print(pnts)



Somewhat convoluted solution, but it's relatively quick on a sample SpatRaster with 8.55e+07 cells:

create negative polygon buffer() of your SpatRaster
convert buffer to line and use to mask() SpatRaster
convert masked SpatRaster to points
subset pnts that are NA and return coordinates of nearest() point from step 3
left_join() result to pnts and generate new geometry
run extract()

You may need to increase width = -1 depending on your actual SpatRaster. Based on your comment and question, I have modified your example data so that it is at a higher resolution and so the NA extent differs for the SpatRasters in the stack.
library(terra)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

# Create high-res version of your raster stack
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package = "terra")
r <- rast(f)
r <- disagg(r, fact = 100)
r <- rep(r, 3) * 1:3
names(r) <- paste0("var", 1:3)
r[1:length(1:(nrow(r) / 2)), , 2] <- NA

# Generate spatial points dataset and add ID column
extent <- as.polygons(ext(r)) %>%
  st_as_sf()

set.seed(99)
pnts <- st_sample(extent, size = 20, type = "random") %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  st_set_crs(crs(r)) %>%
  mutate(ID = 1:n())

# Create spatvector of points just inside extent of r_non_na
sv_poly <- as.polygons(r)
sv_poly <- aggregate(sv_poly)
buff <- buffer(sv_poly, width = -1)
sv_line <- as.lines(buff)
sv_mask <- mask(r, sv_line)
sv_points <- as.points(sv_mask)

# Identify which pnts contain NAs and subset
values <- extract(r, pnts)

pnts1 <- bind_cols(pnts, select(values, starts_with("var"))) %>%
  filter(if_any(starts_with("var"), is.na))

# Get point from sv_points nearest to each pnts1 
pnts2 <- data.frame(nearest(vect(pnts1), sv_points)) %>%
  bind_cols(pnts1, .) %>%
  select(ID, to_x, to_y) %>%
  st_drop_geometry()

# Join result to pnts and generate new sf based on updated coordinates
pnts2 <- left_join(pnts, pnts2, by = "ID") %>%
  mutate(
    to_x = if_else(is.na(to_x), st_coordinates(x)[, 1], to_x),
    to_y = if_else(is.na(to_y), st_coordinates(x)[, 2], to_y)
  ) %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("to_x", "to_y"), crs = crs(r))

values <- extract(r, pnts2)

pnts <- left_join(pnts, values, by = "ID")

data.frame(pnts)
#    ID var1 var2 var3                         x
# 1   1  352  704 1056 POINT (6.204564 49.61259)
# 2   2  415  830 1245 POINT (5.831744 49.50206)
# 3   3  320  640  960 POINT (6.283376 50.05788)
# 4   4  178  356  534   POINT (6.527403 49.885)
# 5   5  320  640  960 POINT (6.165203 50.02171)
# 6   6  188  376  564 POINT (6.506903 49.70423)
# 7   7  248  496  744 POINT (6.273213 49.44621)
# 8   8  467  934 1401 POINT (5.974874 50.05255)
# 9   9  315  630  945 POINT (6.025371 49.44255)
# 10 10  338  676 1014 POINT (5.880458 49.59218)
# 11 11  320  640  960 POINT (6.176147 49.81675)
# 12 12  290  580  870 POINT (6.141816 49.68429)
# 13 13  379  758 1137 POINT (5.895121 49.70175)
# 14 14  320  640  960 POINT (6.245882 49.85078)
# 15 15  214  428  642 POINT (6.286175 49.47203)
# 16 16  328  656  984 POINT (6.248484 49.77455)
# 17 17  461  922 1383  POINT (6.024993 49.9599)
# 18 18  467  934 1401  POINT (5.82288 50.05956)
# 19 19  467  934 1401 POINT (5.819084 49.89676)
# 20 20  467  934 1401 POINT (5.886452 50.17475)

You can use the two columns pnts2 sf to compare which points required 'shifting'.

Thank you for this! I'm not quite sure I can get this to work for me though. I believe it assumes all rasters in the stack have the same extent (and therefore each point will have the same number of NAs) which is NOT the case. For example when you create pnts1 you filter by NAs in the first variable. This would lead to non-NA values in other columns being lost. Each raster in the stack has to be treated seperately

@seak23 - sorry for the delay, an extra step was needed to accommodate situations where the NA extent may differ between layers in the stack. That's because mask() will ignore any areas in the stack even if only one of the layers has an NA. Key changes are 1) the sample data used, 2) the addition of the r_non_na object, and 3) the modified filter() for pnts1 to ensure any NAs are returned. Let me know if it works for your actual data.

I really appreciate your help! I haven't applied it to my dataset yet, but i'm noticing that var2 in your example still has NA values being returned

@seak23 - haha, I think I had it right previously but second-guessed myself due to the repeated values for pnts[c(8, 18:20),]. I have updated it and it should be ok now.
